# How to test wether uploaded file is an epub file?

Tags: php

Hey so this is a very simple question, but one I just can't find the answer for.
I know this is how you test wether the file you uploaded is indeed an image file:

```
if($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
```

Just swapping the `png` with wichever file extension you accept.
I just want to know how do I use this statement to test for a file that is an .epub file? What is the first part before the `/` going to be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think only to use
 if($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "epub")

Comment: I think it should be `application/epub+zip`.

Answer (score 1):

Just write a simple upload script that prints `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` on the screen and upload a file of the wanted type

Answer (score 0):

```
if (pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == "epub") {}
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Answer (score 0):

The `type` is the client-provided MIME information. Some of the info for this is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#introduction) I found on internet

Try

```
($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "epub")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I wrote a script that just outputs the file type and the output was "application/octet-stream"

This also worked to test wether the file is of type epub.